# How to call multiple fetch APIs

Tags: javascript

I have to make a fetch call at a url and after getting its response I want to use those results to call another fetch. I have following code:-

```
async function getDate(request) {
  let data;
  console.log('handle request called')
  await fetch('<first-url>')
    .then(res => {
      let urls = res.json()
      console.log('urls are ', urls)
      return urls.data
    })
    .then((urls) => {
      let url = urls[0]
      console.log('url is ', url)
      return fetch(url)
    })
    .then((res) => {
      data = res.body
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("something went wrong")
    })
  return new Response(data, {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'text/html' },
  })
}
```

I followed the above method after following [this](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-use-the-fetch-method-to-make-multiple-api-calls-with-vanilla-javascript/) tutorial. However it does not seem to work and I am getting `urls are {Promise:[Pending]}`.

Comment: Are you awaiting for `getDate`

Comment: @JayVasant No. It's callback function being called in some other function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Use Promises.all

Comment: Your primary issue is res.json() returns a promise and either has to be awaited or you have to add it to the promise chain. I would also convert everything to either await or promise chain. Mixing them just leads to confusion.

Comment: @Neal is absolutely right about why this is failing. `Promise.all` is irrelevant to the actual problem, and can't actually be used when the URL for the second request depends on the response to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here issue with return `res.json()`. res.json() is `promisable` object, so u have to resolve it to get data.

For your example:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function getDate() {
  let data;
  console.log("handle request called");
  return await fetch('<first-url>')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((urls) => {
      console.log("urls are ", urls);
      if (urls.length)
        return Promise.all(urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((x) => x.json())));
      return [];
    })
    .then((responses) => {
      console.log("urls are ", responses);
      return responses;
    });
}
getDate().then(console.log);
```

**Sample:**

```js
async function getDate() {
  let data;
  console.log("handle request called");
  return await fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/countries")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((urls) => {
      console.log("urls are ", urls);
      return urls;
    });
}
getDate().then(console.log);
```